# Problem with encoding of character strings when loading json files to RStudio under Windows 10

Tags: r, json, character-encoding, windows-10, tweets

I am trying to *extract Tweets from json files and save them as RData under Windows 10 and using RStudio version 1.2.5033 and streamR*. However, Windows (and RStudio and streamR subsequently) assumes that the input is Windows-1252 although it is UTF-8 which leads to **serious encoding issues**.

To replicate the problem, please use [this json file](https://uni-koeln.sciebo.de/s/rIUMrMni6NsabdE) with two fake Tweets since I could not replicate the structure of the original json files within R. But this structure leads to issues with the only solution I found for the encoding issue (see below).

The **code I used** is the following:

```
df <- streamR::parseTweets("test.json")
```

The **output I get** with df$text is: '[1] "RT @bkabka:EikÃ¶ tÃ¤mÃ¤" "RT @bkabka:EspaÃ±a"'.

The **output should be**: '[1] "RT @bkabka:Eikö tämä" "RT @bkabka:España"'.

My question is therefore: **(How) can I tell R and streamR to interpret the text as being encoded using UTF-8 rather than Windows-1252?**

Since all this happens because the function wrongly assumes that the text is encoded with Windows-1252, **one solution** would be to go through the whole corpus and replace all of these wrongly interpreted special characters with the correct one, for example using the table I found [here](https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html). In my case however, the corpus is very very large making this a very suboptimal solution in the long run. Additionally, I would not have the possibility to check whether it actually replaced all special characters correctly.

---

**Some additional information**:

Using rjson and the following code somehow makes R interpret the encoding correctly, but has troubles with the structure of the json files since it only extracts the first line:

```
lt <- rjson::fromJSON(file="test.json")
```

I guess it cannot extract the subsequent line because it does not recognise the line break which is an actual line break and not \n or any other character combination. Unfortunately, I do not have the possibility to change the json files.

The json files were created by another person under macOS using streamR - if I am not mistaken.

The same problem appears using simple R instead of RStudio. The problem does not appear on macOS.

The problem is even more serious when using tweet2r, the only other package I am aware of that allows to extract Tweets from json files using R. Tweet2r deletes specific special characters such as "¶" and thus, the wrongly interpreted special characters cannot be replaced anymore with the correct ones.

Comment: I'm not sure what output is required, but you can read that file in with `jsonlite::stream_in(file("~/../Downloads/test.json"))` with the proper encoding.

Comment: Thank you and so simple. Sorry for not trying this myself. I added this and some things to keep in mind when solving my issue like this as an answer. I am happy to delete the answer if you prefer to put your name on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MrFlick (see his comment), here is a **solution using jsonlite** that results in a very similar data frame structure and reads the encoding correctly:

```
df <- jsonlite::stream_in(file("~/../Downloads/test.json"))
```

Just some further information for those being used to the luxury of streamR handling tweets that might encounter a similar issue in the future, there are **two main differences in the data frames created by parseTweets and stream_in**:

1. parseTweets does not extract data for broken Tweets. stream_in does. Hence, the data frame has more rows when using stream_in but contains the same Tweets.
2. stream_in creates fewer variables since some of the columns in the data frame are themselves data frames. This might lead to issues when using the data frame without further transforming the data frame created with stream_in. parseTweets does that for you.